# Optimizing many "BETWEEN ? AND ?" where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to grab vehicles that have mileage within a certain `$range` and `$interval`. Currently, there are a huge number of `between ? and ?` clauses which are slowing the query down immensely. Is there a better way of accomplishing this? I'm thinking a modulo operation might work, although the `$range` makes it more difficult.

```
$interval = 15000;
$range = 5000;
$max = 3000000;

for ($i = $interval; $i < $max; $i += $interval)
{
    $between = [
        $i - $range,
        $i + $range,
    ];

    // generates "WHERE mileage BETWEEN ? AND ? OR mileage BETWEEN ? AND ? ..."
    $query->orWhereBetween('mileage', $between);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select .. where (mileage>=15000) and ((mileage-10000) mod 15000)<=10000
```

Comment: What's up with the `-10000`?

Comment: @Shane It's distance between min/max, i.e  $range*2